# Minimising kurtosis (non-convex). Can I use algebraic geometry or alternate methods to show uniqueness of a particular solution?

Tags: co.combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization, intersection-theory, real-algebraic-geometry, non-convex-optimization

I consider a weighted sum of $n$ identically-distributed correlated random variables. The weights in the sum, $w_i$ for $i=1, 2,...,n$, satisfy $w_i>=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i=1$. I am investigating solutions that minimise the kurtosis of this sum over the $w_i$.

The kurtosis of the sum is the ratio of the fourth moment to the square of the variance and can be written as follows: $K=\frac{u}{v}$ where $u(w)=\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^{n} w_i w_j w_k w_l \mu_{ijkl}$ and $v(w)=(\sum_{i,j}^{n} w_i w_j \sigma_{ij})^2$. $\mu_{ijkl}$ are centralised fourth order co-moments and $\sigma_{ij}$ centralised second order co-moments i.e. the covariance, which are fixed for a given problem.

In addition to $u(w)>=v(w)$, $u$ and $v$ have some special properties worth noting:

1. Both are non-negative convex functions that can be written as a sum-of-squares.
2. Both are polynomials in the $w_i$ that contain all, and only, monomials of order 4.
3. Both are homogeneous functions of order 4, which implies e.g. $\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \frac{\delta u}{\delta w_i}=4u$.

$K$ is therefore a homogeneous function of order $0$ and, though $u$ and $v$ are convex, $K$ is neither a convex nor a quasi-convex function. However, based on looking at many numerical examples I believe that in the case of correlations all being non-negative and $<1$, there is only one minimum that must therefore be global.

My question is whether I can prove this to be the case (or construct a counterexample) but it seems difficult when the function itself is not convex. I believe that algebraic geometry or intersection theory could be the best route to an answer; however, these are relatively new fields for me. Could someone kindly help? Below is what I have done so far.

Non-negative correlations imply that all of the $\mu_{ijkl}$ and $\sigma_{ij}$ are non-negative too, so that $u$ and $v$ are convex polynomials in the $w_i$ with non-negative coefficients. The first order Kuhn-Tucker conditions for the optimisation yield, after some simplification:

1. $w_i>=0$
2. $\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i = 1$
3. $w_i \frac{\delta u}{\delta w_i}/u(w)=w_i \frac{\delta v}{\delta w_i}/v(w) \implies v(w)*w_i \frac{\delta u}{\delta w_i}=u(w)*w_i \frac{\delta v}{\delta w_i}$
4. $\frac{\delta u}{\delta w_i}/u(w)>=\frac{\delta v}{\delta w_i}/v(w) \implies v(w)*\frac{\delta u}{\delta w_i}>=u(w)*\frac{\delta v}{\delta w_i}$.

Items 2 and 3 represent a system of polynomial equations over domains 1 and 4 and also the intersection of a hyperplane and $n$ related polynomials. To explore potential solutions I am using Mathematica. It struggles to solve 1-4 simultaneously, but easily solves 1-3. Filtering those results that satisfy 4 so far produces a unique solution for many hundreds of examples. (For completeness I do have a separate optimiser which is guaranteed to find the global minimum of the original problem).

I wondered if there are any known pieces of work or theorems that can speak to the expected number of solutions to 1-3 or 1-4? I am aware of Bézout's theorem and the like but feel the specific properties of $u$ and $v$ may offer a much more specific understanding of the solutions.

Thanks.

PS I have more colour on what solutions of 1-3 look like and in practice I use a different formulation in Mathemtica for simplicity but I do not believe it affects my question.

Comment: X-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3898165

Comment: *Non-negative correlations imply that all of the $\mu_{ijkl}$ are non-negative* Are you sure? I do not see that (unless by "correlations" you mean something unusual). Can you elaborate on this point?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the question. I am using a Gaussian copula to define the dependence structure between marginal distributions, which I have chosen to be symmetric and fat-tailed e.g. a Laplace distribution that has excess kurtosis of 3. The dependence is therefore defined by only the correlation matrix and if the correlations are non-negative, then I believe any fourth order co-moment $\mu_{ijkl}=E[x_i x_j x_k x_l]$ must be non-negative too. I would need to think more about how prove it.

Comment: For further comfort I just ran 1000 examples using non-negative correlation matrices and didn't find any negative $\mu_{ijkl}$. By definition $E[x_i x_j]=\rho_{ij}\ge0\;\forall\; i,j$. There are also other points of comfort e.g. if $i$ is uncorrelated to $j,k,l$ then $\mu_{ijkl}=E[x_i]E[x_j x_k x_l]=0$ since  $E[x_i]=0\;\forall\; i$. Also, if $i,j$ are uncorrelated with $k,l$ then $\mu_{ijkl}=E[x_i x_j]E[x_k x_l]=\rho_{ij}\rho_{kl}\ge0$.

Comment: More generally as correlations between $i$,$j$,$k$ and $l$ increase towards 1 then the maximum value of $\mu_{ijkl}=E[x_i^4]=c\;\forall\;i$, where $c$ is a constant equal to the kurtosis of the chosen marginal distribution e.g. for a Laplace marginal the kurtosis is 6 (excess kurtosis 3).

Comment: As a quick point of clarity for the above, I am assuming unit variances for simplicity so $\sigma_{ij}=\rho_{ij}$.